# How to pass a shell function to `git rebase --exec`

Tags: bash, git, shell, rebase, git-rebase

In bash, to pass a variable or function to a child process, you need to export it.

```
#!/bin/bash

f() { echo hello; }

# calling shell function `f` in child process
bash -c "f" # bash: f: command not found

# export the function
export -f f
bash -c "f" # "hello"
```

However, I can't seem to achieve the same result with `git rebase --exec`

```
#!/bin/bash

f() { echo hello; }

# export the function
export -f f
git rebase --exec "f" # does not work
git rebase --exec "bash -c 'f'" # does not work
```

I know I could declare the function inline: `git rebase --exec 'f() { echo hello; }; f'` or put the function in another script and call it: `git rebase --exec './f.sh'`

Is there a way to make it work? What am I missing?

Comment: On some systems the example you provide works perfectly well when run without changes, emitting `hello` between `Executing: bash -c f` lines. What's your `/bin/sh`? (We need to know if it filters out environment variables it doesn't recognize instead of passing them through).

Comment: I am using GNU bash 5.1.16 on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: We don't care about the bash version, we care about the sh version; modern Ubuntu means it's dash. If dash eats the variable, then bash can't see it; next step is to see if that's actually true.

Comment: (because git starts sh with your `bash -c 'f'` argument as a command, and then sh starts bash; so we need to care about whether `sh` eats the exported function before bash is invoked)

Comment: ...okay, yes, dash _does_ eat (what it sees as) environment variables with poorly-formed names, so that explains the problem. You can test this yourself easily: Compare `env` to `sh -c env`

Comment: Yes, `sh` is a symlink pointing to `dash`

Comment: I'm looking into whether git allows the shell it invokes to be parameterized.

Comment: ...okay, after digging into the codebase a little, `run-command.c`'s `prepare_shell_cmd` is what does the work of setting up an argument vector. The bad news is that it hardcodes `sh`; the good news is that it's not hardcoding `/bin/sh`, so one could set up PATH to make bash the first `sh`.

Comment: (I did write an answer using the PATH approach suggested above, by the way; but not having an Ubuntu system handy I'm not in a position to test it in practice; folks with the 10k rep necessary to view deleted answers should be able to see it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. Thanks to [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for his help.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

f() {
  for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
  done
}

printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "$(declare -f f); f" # serialise function f
export cmd_q
printf -v args '%q ' "$@" # serialise arguments f
export args

# remove -r --root and adapt to your needs here
git rebase -r --root --exec $'bash -c "eval $cmd_q \'$args\'"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash's `export -f` is a nice hack rather than something "standard". See the following commands and outputs (on Linux):

```
$ foo() { echo hello; }
$ export -f foo
$ bash -c foo
hello
$ bash -c 'tr "\0" "\n" < /proc/$$/environ | grep -A 1 foo'
BASH_FUNC_foo%%=() {  echo hello
}
```

As we can see, bash puts the exported `foo()`'s definition in an env var named `BASH_FUNC_foo%%`.

If current bash's subprocess is another bash, the sub-bash would happily recognize this weird env var and restore it as a function and all works expected.

But if the subprocess is not bash, then the behavior is undefined. The subprocess may choose to pass the weird env var over to its subprocess, but it can also choose to unset this weird env var <sup>(because it looks weird/invalid or may be malicious!)</sup> so its subprocess <sup>(say, another bash)</sup> would not see it.

---

Note that the env var naming format for exported functions was ever [changed](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-09/msg00278.html) to deal with the [shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) issue.

Comment: This is accurate, but it buries the answer in background and explanation (and provides the answer only as supposition or speculation; the OP has indicated that they're using Ubuntu, which has dash for sh, and dash _definitely does_ filter out environment variable names that don't map to valid shell variables, so it's possible to speak with much more authority on the subject). Maybe lead with the answer, and follow up with the background to understand why it's correct?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate that you go in depth about what's going on under the hood. I'm trying to edit your command and escape the quotes (my biggest nightmare whenever I do bash scripting) to get the environment of the `--exec` subcommand.

Comment: @Haltarys The purpose of constructs like `printf %q`, `${var@Q}`, `declare -p`/`declare -f`/etc. is to escape content automatically in a manner that's guaranteed to be correct if it's unescaped by the same shell version. You shouldn't ever need to do escaping in bash by hand.

Comment: @Haltarys take a look at my [mquote (magic quote)](https://github.com/clarkwang/magic-aliases) -- no more quoting nightmares!

Answer (score 2):

Try serializing the function to text:

```
f() { echo hello; }
git rebase --exec "$(printf "%q " bash -c "$(declare -f f); f")"
```

Comment: This is a bit of automation around the "declare the function inline" thing the OP already knows they can do, no? It's a good practical answer, which is why I've upvoted it, but I'm not sure it's complete.

Comment: I'm sorry but I keep getting this error no matter how much I escape the quotes in the command : `Executing: bash -c $'f () \n{ \n    echo hello\n}; f'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token \`\n{'
bash: -c: line 1: \`$f () \n{ \n    echo hello\n}; f'
warning: execution failed: bash -c $'f () \n{ \n    echo hello\n}; f'`

Comment: @Haltarys, ahh, right; bash's `printf %q` only guarantees that bash will be able to parse the result; it's not POSIX-compliant for use by dash.

Comment: @Haltarys, ...now, if you're willing to start a tiny bit of Python, its `shlex.quote()` _is_ POSIX-compliant, so one can very much write a variant of this answer that works even with dash in play.

Comment: But the fact that the command is invoked with `bash -c` should override the fact that git uses dash, no?

Comment: @Haltarys, sh parses the command _first_ and passes the result to bash; it has to be legal syntax to that copy of (what in your case is) dash.

Comment: @KamilCuk, do you mind if I edit this to provide an option using Python's `shlex` module instead of `printf %q`?

Comment: How about just `SHELL=bash git rebase --exec "$(declare -f f); f"`? Then I wonder, `export -f f; SHELL=bash git rebase --exec f`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, git doesn't honor `SHELL`; read `prepare_shell_cmd` in `run-command.c`.

Comment: I took it from man git rebase https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase : `The "exec" command launches the command in a shell (the one specified in $SHELL, or the default shell if $SHELL is not set)`

Answer (score 1):

As previously discussed, exported functions are stored in environment variables in a namespace that POSIX does not speak to; shells are neither required to pass through such names to children, nor prohibited from doing so.

One easy workaround is to put `eval`able content into an environment variable with an unambiguously legal name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
f() { echo hello; }

cmd_q="$(declare -f f); f"
cmd_q=$cmd_q git rebase --exec $'bash -c \'eval "$cmd_q"\'' "$@"
```

Comment: I'm guessing `-v` is to store the output in the variable `cmd_q` though I don't see it on the man page. But I am not familiar with `eval` and the `$''` syntax

Comment: Your guess re: `-v` is correct. `$''` is ansi C-like strings, a non-POSIX extension that allows backslash escapes to be interpreted by the shell -- `printf %q` using that extension in bash is why KamilCuk's answer failed for you, but here we're using `eval` to parse the `printf`-generated string only after bash has actually started. `eval` parses and executes a string; it's very dangerous if not used carefully (can cause data to leak into syntax with attendant security issues), but `printf %q` generates content that `eval` will reverse to original form if it's the same shell on both sides.

Comment: @Haltarys Re: `printf -v`, by the way, instead of `man printf` read `help printf` or the relevant part of `man bash` -- you want to be reading the docs for the bash-builtin version of printf, not the standalone executable version (which is what the general printf man page covers).

Comment: This is weird because `which printf` outputs `/usr/bin/printf` so I'm confused as to why I'm using the shell builtin instead.

Comment: @Haltarys, `which` isn't part of the shell; it doesn't know that shell builtins exist in the first place, so it can't tell you when something is such a builtin. Don't use or trust it in bash; use `type printf` instead. (Compare output of `type printf` to `type which`, which will likewise tell you that `which` is something like `/usr/bin/which`).

Comment: OK. That's different from what `zsh` does. I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: Yup, zsh is entirely its own deliberately-incompatible-with-everyone-else thing.

Comment: I slept on the problem and found a solution thanks to you : `git rebase --exec $'bash -c "eval $cmd_q"'`

Comment: No backslashes in there so you can just use single quotes instead of the ANSI C-like form. That said, there are some subtle bugs if there aren't double quotes around the argument to eval when it reaches the inner shell, so that solution isn't quite ideal. (You don't want globs in your expression to be expanded before that expression reaches the parser; that can even cause security problems if the code is run in a directory with a hostile filename, and it can cause correctness problems much more easily).

Comment: @Haltarys, anyhow, if you had to make that change it means I didn't `export cmd_q`, and that's an easy bug to fix

Comment: @Haltarys, also, `args="$@"` is badly buggy; you can't just dump an array into a string without losing information, since arrays are more expressive (they can contain spaces as literal data, and also have separators distinguishing the start and end of smaller strings within them, without confusing those two things).

Comment: `cmd_q=$cmd_q git rebase --exec $'bash -c \'eval "$cmd_q"\'' "$@"` makes git think the arguments are for the `rebase` command, not part of the `--exec` command. Unfortunately, I don't see how else to pass the arguments. (You can't pass arrays as variables to child processes, I think)

Comment: Update here's my working solution so far : `printf -v args '%q ' "$@" ; export args ; git rebase -r --root --exec $'bash -c "eval $cmd_q \'$args\'"'`

Comment: I _did_ assume you wanted arguments to be passed to `rebase` not to the command -- if you don't pass arguments to `rebase` how do you tell it what to rebase onto or which commit to start at? Which is to say, the answer does what I meant it to do; if you wanted something different, the question should have said so.

Comment: (Yes, you're correct that you can't pass arrays through the environment; there are tricks, like passing a series of `arr_001`/`arr_002`/`arr_003` variables and then iterating over `"${!arr_@}"` to construct them into an array later, but those tricks are rarely necessary; using `printf '%q '` to generate a single string is exactly the right thing)

Comment: I use `git rebase --root -r --exec "something"` in my use case but I omitted it because it wasn't relevant. Thank you for your help!